# Thought CTEs were syntactic sugar

Tags: sql-server, cte

I was asked to test a change to a query, moving a Table Valued Function (TVF) into a CTE (non-recursive).  My understanding was that each CTE reference is executed separately, so there was a possibility of the change leading to tempdb contention...

I was very surprised to see the query performance improve when using the CTE.  IE:

```
 ;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.col FROM dbo.getValues() t)
 SELECT ...
   JOIN cte c ...
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ...
   JOIN cte c ...
```

Can anyone shed any light on why this is happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524072/evaluation-of-ctes-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: Also this answer and the comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/706983/61305

Comment: See [Provide a hint to force intermediate materialization of CTEs or derived tables](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/) that shows how this can be achieved using `TOP ... ORDER BY` and [Quassnoi's blog](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/28/generating-xml-in-subqueries/) that uses `USE PLAN` to achieve this. Whether that is relevant to you or not who knows without more details / an actual execution plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the behavior is that the CTE is "expected" to be evaluated multiple times, but it doesn't always work that way (e.g. it is not guaranteed). There are probably a lot of variables that dictate the behavior one way or the other. Can you share an actual execution plan?